# how to show last tikets from whmcs to site

Tags: php, show, whmcs

i want do something to show last tickets in site

for example i have folder /whmcs
and my site is examble.com/

i want show tikets from whmcs. i use this code to get first name and show form for log in at my site, but in info at user want add last tikets or show last tiket name and link for the ticket.

how to do that??

```
<?php
    include("../whmcs/dbconnect.php"); 
    if ($_SESSION['uid']) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM tblclients WHERE id='".$_SESSION['uid']."' LIMIT 1;");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            echo "<div class='after'><p id='login'><span>".$_LANG['welcomeback'].', '.$row['firstname'].' <br /><a href="../sup/clientarea.php">'.$_LANG['clientareatitle'].'</a> | <a href="../sup/submitticket.php">اضف تذكرة</a></span></p><div class="out"><a href="../sup/logout.php">خروج</a></div></div>';
        }else{
            echo '<div class="before">
        <form action="../sup/dologin.php?goto=clientarea.php" method="post">';?>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="" />
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="البريد الالكتروني" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='البريد الالكتروني'" onclick="value=''" />
            <?php  
            echo '<input name="password" id="password" type="password" value="" />
                      <label><div class="rememberme">تذكرني</div>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" />
                      <span class="state"></span>
                      </label>
                      <input type="submit" value="دخول" />
                      </form>
                      <a href="../sup/pwreset.php" class="lost" title="نسيت كلمة المرور؟">نسيت كلمة المرور؟</a>
                      <a href="../sup/register.php" title="التسجيل">التسجيل</a>
                      </div>';
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: That code is a huge mess, I can't format it properly. Seems incomplete.

Comment: work with me good
edit ../whmcs/dbconnect.php for path of whmcs